# Extracting variable value from script with Nokogiri - Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have this code which pulls in all the scripts on a page.

```
full_url = URI.join(url, "/").to_s #https://www.example.com

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(full_url))

doc.css('script').each do |script|
    puts script.content
end
```

This works great and returns all scripts on the page. However, that makes it more complicated than it needs to be as I only need 1 script, the one with the class "analytics"

```
<script class="analytics">
</script>
```

But I can't find a good way to isolate only that script by class, otherwise I have to loop through all the other scripts when I know the value I need is inside this one.

Now the 2nd issue I have is there is a bunch of functions and try/catches etc in the script.
Within that I only need the value of these 2 lines:

```
window.TEST.gameName = "pop1";
window.TEST.gameVersion = "1.1.2";
```

So I just want to return the values "pop1" and "1.1.2"

There will only be 1 instance of window.TEST.gameName and window.TEST.gameVersion so they will be unique. Maybe I am overcomplicating it using Nokogiri and I should just use regex or would this way be quicker?

I am not tied to Nokogiri either, just that seemed like the most popular option.

I tried a few variations of using doc.at and doc.search but I just keep getting nothing back so I am probably doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`css`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable:css) will take a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). `script.analytics` finds script tags of the analytics class.

```
doc.css('script.analytics').each do |script|
    puts script.content
end
```

As to the second part, `window.TEST.gameName = "pop1";` is Javascript. Nokogiri cannot help you. You'd need a Javascript parser.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Schwern's question and answer the full question.

I used

```
doc.css('script.analytics').each do |script|
    @script = script.content
end
```

That gave me that script which was about a hundred lines of javascript, always in the same format, just different values.

I then did:

```
game_name = @script.match(/window.TEST.gameName = "(.*?)";/m)[1].strip # returns pop1
game_version = @script.match(/window.TEST.gameVersion = "(.*?)";/m)[1].strip # returns 1.1.2
```

There are more likely better ways to do it but that worked for me.